# How to run a query in postgres-node equal to psql "\copy" command?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a shell script that runs a command:

```
psql -h $DBHOST -U $DBUSERNAME -c "\copy sometable FROM '$PWD/sometable.csv' WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER"
```

which works fine.

Now, as I have some requirements to implement more advanced logic, I am migrating some of these commands to nodejs code.

Is it possible to run this `\copy` command with `postgres-node`?

If not, I see an alternative to run this command as it is as a shell command from nodejs with `require('child_process').spawn`.

Answer (score 4):

you are looking for https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-copy-streams I suppose. It's same authors "extension" to `node-pg`